# pull to refresh up and down refresh for dynamic table layout in android

Tags: android

am adding dynamic views in my activity,which is under `TableLayout`.how to do pullup and pulldown refresh.

```
TableLayout tl =(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
LayoutInflater vi =(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Question :) It will surely help you :) Good Luck

[Android PullTo Refresh on ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373362/android-pullto-refresh-on-scrollview/11391896#11391896)

Comment: i seen this example already,but they did for grid ,list,webview..I wanted to knw for tablelayout

Comment: Yeah i know :) from that example you can make your custom pull to refresh for any component. i also got success with it.

Comment: And You need to modify some of the lines in library project

Comment: sure give your emailID. i ll send custom library project to u

Comment: got it .. send you after some time

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13669/discussion-between-xitij-and-balajee-annamalai)